# Using / in query strings

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use query strings in ASP.NET. I have a requirement of the following format

`http://localhost/website/1/?callback=?`

Here 1 denotes the ID of the profile. This means some info from id=1 will be fetched through the string

If this would have been `website/2/?callback=?` , then the id would be 2. My questions is to how do I use this `/id/` as a query string so it can be used to fetch the profile ID. This was my first preference to use `/id/` format otherwise I could look into fetching using two `?'s`

If the id =1, I want to fetch ID=1 particulars from DB on this page. `http://localhost/website/1/?callback=?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the ID is in the PATH, not the query string.  You can access the path via `Request.Path` in an ASPX page.  From there you would need to do some string parsing to get at the portion of the path where you expect the ID to be.

In your case I would probably use something like `int.Parse(Request.Path.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1])`, but please note that I've made that line pretty dense for brevity's sake.  For starters, you should use `int.TryParse()` instead of `int.Parse()`.  This code assumes that the ID will always be in the same place in the url.  For example, it will work for "/website/2/" and "/user/2/", but not for "/website/somethingelse/2/".

Answer (score 0):

UriTemplate might be a good choice for that sort of parsing.  Not to mention, probably a bit more clear and explicit about what's happening.

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate(v=VS.90).aspx